# php ZipArchive check if Zip file is broken/incomplete

Tags: php, zip

My users upload zip files through FTP, then a php file adds them to a RSS file.

I'm trying to find a way to check each ZIP files to validate the file and check if it is broken or if the upload is unfinished. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 18):

The result from `open` can be also be `true`, **which should be evaluated first.** Without the check `ZipArchive:ER_NOZIP`, which equals (int) 1, will always match.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CHECKCONS);
if ($res !== TRUE) {
    switch($res) {
        case ZipArchive::ER_NOZIP:
            die('not a zip archive');
        case ZipArchive::ER_INCONS :
            die('consistency check failed');
        case ZipArchive::ER_CRC :
            die('checksum failed');
        default:
            die('error ' . $res);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine. Although it will also unzip Excels and similar files which is unwanted most often.

Comment: I am getting error like : Undefined class constant 'CHECKCONS'

Comment: @h0tw1r3 : As of PHP 5.3 this extension is built-in. Before, Windows users need to enable php_zip.dll inside of php.ini in order to use these functions.

Comment: I am using php7, wamp, windows 10

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ZipArchive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php) class for this. Since PHP5.2 it is part of the standard php distribution.

Use it like this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

// ZipArchive::CHECKCONS will enforce additional consistency checks
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CHECKCONS);
if(!$res) {
    throw Exception('Error opening zip');
}

switch($res) {

    case ZipArchive::ER_NOZIP :
        die('not a zip archive');
    case ZipArchive::ER_INCONS :
        die('consistency check failed');
    case ZipArchive::ER_CRC :
        die('checksum failed');
    
    // ... check for the other types of errors listed in the manual
}
```

If the zip archive is incomplete or broken in other ways `$zip->open()` will return `ZipArchive::ER_NOZIP`

Comment: i already know how to check if it is a zip archive, i want to check if the file is incomplete or broken

Comment: Seems that you didn't understand the trick: if the archive is broken `$zip->open()` will return `ER_NOZIP`

Comment: i just tested it and it always prints "not a zip archive" even when testing with a valid zip archive

Comment: Yes then *additional* consistency checks are performed. Will add this to the answer. But however even without this the example should find corrupted archives as the usual consistency checks are enabled by default. (had a look into the siurce code). What is your current problem? didn't it detect some corrupted archives?

Comment: You need a condition if ($res !== true) switch ($res) { otherwise it will trigger the first case.

Comment: @tim thanks for the input (to this old post)! I'll add this. Fyi, another thing you could in PHP is: `switch(true) { case $res === ZipArchive::ER_NOZIP: ... and so on }`

Answer (score 2):

How to detect corrupt files with CRC mismatch:

ZipArchive seems unable to detect broken files. ZipArchive::CHECKCONS doesn't help, only if it's not a ZIP file at all. It happily decompressed corrupt files in my tests and the client downloading the data is not informed.

Creating a corrupt archive for testing is simple - zip some files and change a byte with a hex editor in the resulting ZIP file. Now you can test the file with a ZIP application to learn which file inside the archive is corrupt.

You can simply verify CRCs on the server for smaller files:

```
<?php
$maxsize = 1024*1024;
$z = new ZipArchive;
$r = $z->open("foo.zip", ZipArchive::CHECKCONS);
if($r !== TRUE)
  die('ZIP error when trying to open "foo.zip": '.$r);

$stat = $z->statName("mybrokenfile.txt");
if($stat['size'] > $maxsize)
  die('File too large, decompression denied');
$s = $z->getStream($file);
$data = stream_get_contents($s, $maxsize);
fclose($s);
if($stat['crc'] != crc32($data))
  die('File is corrupt!');
//echo 'File is valid';

//you may send the file to the client now if you didn't output anything before
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mybrokenfile.txt"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . $stat['size']);
ob_clean();
echo $data;
$z->close();
?>
```

If the file shall not be fully decompressed on the server but decompressed while streaming to the client due to it's size, the file transfer already startet and printing an error message later doesn't work. Maybe the best way would be to interrupt the connection before closing the file transfer. The client should be able to detect this as corrupt download.
On the server side a function is needed, that can calculate the CRC32 on streamed data stepwise.

Comment: Working as designed. CHECKCONS does not validate the files inside of the archive, only the consistency of the archive itself.